# Drag file to system doesn't work in Linux (Qt)

Tags: linux, qt, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to realise dragndrop files from app to system.
It works on Windows explorer, partially works on Linux - I can drag files to browser, for example, or notepad (any app), but system show abandoned cursor when I'm trying to drag it to folder or desktop
Here is the code:

```
QUrl url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(fname);
QDrag* drag = new QDrag(this);
QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData;
mimeData->setUrls(QList<QUrl>() << url);
drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction, Qt::CopyAction);
```

Help please